# How to replace pd.Series list values with dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, replace, series

After stemming words with NLTK, got dictionary:

```
> {'golden': 'gold',  'wonderfully': 'wonder',  'damaging': 'damag', 
> 'useless': 'use',  'toys': 'toy',  'ducks': 'duck'}
```

So I want replace existing words in pd.Series (where values are lists):

```
0              ['want', 'buy', 'toys', 'ducks']
1                                    ['street']
2     ['damaging', 'toys', 'isolating', 'toys']
3                       ['useless', 'clothing']
```

I want output as a (*replace* toys for toy etc.. as in the dictionary):

```
0                ['want', 'buy', 'toy', 'duck']
1                                    ['street']
2          ['damag', 'toy', 'isolating', 'toy']
3                           ['use', 'clothing']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `explode` then `replace` and `agg` back ,`d` is your dict

```
out = s.explode().replace(d).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Comment: That solution is indeed working. Just use `d` to define the lookup dictionary (maybe that was unclear).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# the replacement dictionary
replacements = {'golden': 'gold', 'wonderfully': 'wonder',
                'damaging': 'damag', 'useless': 'use', 'toys': 'toy', 'ducks': 'duck'}

# setup of the Series
s = pd.Series([['want', 'buy', 'toys', 'ducks'],
               ['street'],
               ['damaging', 'toys', 'isolating', 'toys'],
               ['useless', 'clothing']])


def replace(lst, repl):
    """This function receives a list and replaces the elements with the values of the keys in repl"""
    return [repl.get(e, e) for e in lst]


out = s.apply(replace, args=(replacements,))
print(out)
```

**Output**

```
0          [want, buy, toy, duck]
1                        [street]
2    [damag, toy, isolating, toy]
3                 [use, clothing]
dtype: object
```